# App Store rejection due to programmatically adding application to all spaces

Tags: app-store, nsuserdefaults, osx-lion, appstore-approval

I have an app submitted to the app store that was rejected due to:

2.30 Apps that do not comply with the Mac OS X File System documentation will be rejected

They claim my app is modifying the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist file which is unsupported.

My app is in fact modifying that file, but only with NSUserDefaults via: (I'm omitting some code for brevity...)

```
NSMutableDictionary *spacesDefaults = 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.spaces"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [spacesDefaults objectForKey:@"app-bindings"];
NSString *bundleId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] lowercaseString];

[dict setObject:@"AllSpaces" forKey:bundleId];
[spacesDefaults setObject:dict forKey:@"app-bindings"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:spacesDefaults 
                                                   forName:@"com.apple.spaces"];
```

It seems to me that this falls under the first bullet of "File-System Usage Requirements for the Mac App Store" http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572

```
* You may use Apple frameworks such as User Defaults, Calendar Store, and Address Book that implicitly write to files in specific locations, including locations is not allowed to access directly.
```

Does anyone know why this would get rejected?  I just don't see it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a *really* important issue [that I bemoaned on the Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/514928#514928)...

And I suppose that filing a [Feedback Request](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) *might* have an effect, someday... But apparently this LAME restriction.. *which limits an App's ability to do ANYTHING* outside the sandbox..  EVEN IF it's something your *user* can do...  **This is a serious step backwards in the ability of third-party apps on the mac to perform SIMPLE, implicit commands by the user.**

This seems like a fundamental paradigm shift on Apple's part.  Here's the jist of the above forum listing..

```
NSUserDefaults can be used only for our own app, 
and sandboxing will not allow to modify other apps defaults
```

Additionally, you cannot modify in any way ANY other app's `.plist`, via XML, or otherwise.

And, no, doing `defaults write` via a task or terminal on another domain, besides YOUR OWN APP is outlawed as well.  Ugh, it's very annoying.